# Python Ctypes passing pointer for data

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I am accessing an API and can't get the data returned. The two float pointers will point to an array of data. I must assume the API is working properly. A different function call provides a the length of the data I am retrieving. This values is `length` down below when attempted.

C Header for Function

```
    int function(int, float * data1, float * data2)
```

ctypes setup

```
    dll.function.argtypes = (c_int, POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float))
    dll.function.restypes = c_int
```

Failed Attempt 1:

```
    x = c_float()
    y = c_float()
    status = dll.function(1, byref(x), byref(y))
```

Program crashes OR Access violation writing.

Failed Attempt 2:

```
    x = POINTER(c_float)()
    y = POINTER(c_float)()
    status = dll.function(1, x, y)
```

Null Pointer Error

Failed Attempt 3:

```
    dll.function.argtypes = (c_int, c_void_p, c_void_p)
    x = c_void_p()
    y = c_void_p()
    status = dll.function(1, x, y)
```

Null Pointer Error

Failed Attempt 4:

```
    array = c_float * length
    x = array()
    y = array()
    status = dll.function(1, byref(x), byref(y))
```

Program crashes

Failed Attempt 5:

```
    array = c_float * length
    x = POINTER(array)()
    y = POINTER(array)()
    status = dll.function(1, x, y)
```

Null Pointer Error OR ArgumentError: expected LP_c_float instance instead of LP_c_float_Array_[length]

Failed Attempt 6:

```
    x = (c_float*length)()
    y = (c_float*length)()
    a = cast(x, POINTER(c_float))
    b = cast(y, POINTER(c_float))
    status = dll.function(1, a, b)
```

Program crashes

What am I missing and why?

I believe the argtypes are correct. I am attempting to meet them properly, but there continues to be an issues. Do I need to "malloc" the memory somehow? (I'm sure I need to free after I get the data).

This is on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 32-bit.

I have looked through other similar issues and am not finding a solution. I am wondering if, at this point, I can blame the API for this issue.

Comment: It is recommended to use cffi instead of ctypes. cffi is much more convenient.https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html A while ago I was also using ctypes, but people recommended to switch. And they were right, I would never tough ctypes again. :)

Comment: Examples on how to use pointers can be found at https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#working-with-pointers-structures-and-arrays

Comment: Both `char*` have the same length? They are allocated inside `function` or should they be allocated by the caller (*Python*)?

Comment: Both float* are pointers to arrays. They will need to be allocated by the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with pointers and arrays is explained in [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Type conversions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions).

I prepared a dummy example for you.

*main00.c*:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DECLSPEC_DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DECLSPEC_DLLEXPORT
#endif


static int kSize = 5;


DECLSPEC_DLLEXPORT int size() {
    return kSize;
}


DECLSPEC_DLLEXPORT int function(int dummy, float *data1, float *data2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < kSize; i++) {
        data1[i] = dummy * i;
        data2[i] = -dummy * (i + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


c_float_p = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)


def main(*argv):
    dll = ct.CDLL("./dll00.so")

    size = dll.size
    size.argtypes = []
    size.restype = ct.c_int


    function = dll.function
    function.argtypes = [ct.c_int, c_float_p, c_float_p]
    function.restype = ct.c_int

    sz = size()
    print(sz)

    data1 = (ct.c_float * sz)()
    data2 = (ct.c_float * sz)()

    res = function(1, ct.cast(data1, c_float_p), ct.cast(data2, c_float_p))
    for i in range(sz):
        print(data1[i], data2[i])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- The *C* part tries to mimic what your *.dll* does (or at least what I understood):

  - *size* - gets the arrays sizes
  - *function* - populates the arrays (till their size - assuming that they were properly allocated by the caller)
- *Python* part is straightforward:

  - Load the *.dll*
  - Define *argtypes* and *restype* (in your code it's *restype*'**s**) for the 2 functions (for *size_func* not necessary)
  - Get the lengths
  - Initialize the arrays
  - Pass them to *function_func* using *ctypes.cast*

**Output** (on *Lnx*, as building the *C* code is much simpler, but works on *Win* as well):

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050043861]> gcc -shared -o dll00.so main00.c
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050043861]> python3 code00.py
> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] 64bit on linux
>
> 5
> 0.0 -1.0
> 1.0 -2.0
> 2.0 -3.0
> 3.0 -4.0
> 4.0 -5.0
> ```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Just accepted. I got pulled away to something else for a week. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing with these float pointers.

If you are trying to *traverse* it, i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%f\n%, data1[i])
```

then for sure this is problematic as no array was allocated. You simply passed a pointer pointing to a float. That is all.

You need to first allocate that memory. To this end Attempt 4 looks like the more promising, but I suspect you have a problem inside your C function leading to the crash.

Difficult to say without seeing the implementation of that function.