# ctypes: decomposing/casting pointer to char into array of pointer to char

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

I'm working with a closed source shared library with example code in C++ like so:

```
// Header
#define MAX_PARAM_NAME             10
int foo(..., char **ParNameList, ...);

// Main
char      *ParNameList = (char *)NULL;
ret = foo(..., &ParNameList,...);
par = (char (*)[MAX_PARAM_NAME])ParNameList;
```

How should it be handled in ctypes?

The problematic part is that in function declaration `foo(..., char **ParNameList, ...);` a `char **` is expected, but a reference to `char *` is actually given in the function call.

So far I have:

```
from ctypes import *
so = cdll.LoadLibrary(...)  
so.foo.argtypes = [                                                                  
...
POINTER(POINTER(c_char)), # ParNameList                       
...
]                                                                                                        
so.foo.restype = c_int                                                               

#...
ParNameList = POINTER(c_char)()
so.foo(..., ParNameList ,...)
```

which gives me a garbage string, where I see the required output is interleaved with random changing RAM bits.

But how does `(char (*)[MAX_PARAM_NAME])` cast work in ctypes?

If there is a more straight forward way for the whole thing, I'd appreciate to hear it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Ctypes passing pointer for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043861/python-ctypes-passing-pointer-for-data)

Comment: I think this is a slightly different case, the problem is in ambiguity of `char **` as per function definition and `char *` in C-Code. In the C-Example the array of char pointers needs to be decomposed after the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to pass the address of the `c_char` pointer using `byref`:

```
foo.argtypes = [..., POINTER(POINTER(c_char)), ...]
foo.restype = c_int

par_name_list = POINTER(c_char)()

# pass by reference
foo(byref(par_name_list))

par = cast(par_name_list, POINTER(c_char * MAX_PARAM_NAME))
```

You may need to free the memory afterwards.

Comment: ctypes-relevant and strange part is the cast of pointer to const length array: `(char (*)[MAX_PARAM_NAME])ParNameList;`

Comment: I think it'd just be `par = cast(par_name_list, POINTER(c_char) * MAX_PARAM_NAME)`.

Comment: actually `POINTER(c_char *MAX_PARAM_NAME)` works!


full line: `print [(cast(par_name_list, POINTER(c_char*MAX_PARAM_NAME) ))[i].value for i in range(ParNumber)]`

Comment: Well there you go :)

Comment: with `POINTER(c_char) * MAX_PARAM_NAME` I get an error `TypeError: cast() argument 2 must be a pointer type, not LP_c_char_Array_10`.

do you mind to include the correct version into your answer, so I can tick it solved?

Comment: Also, on second thought you'd probably want to use `create_string_buffer()` instead of `POINTER(c_char)()` to create a mutable string to pass to `foo` as it's more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

There is pythonic workaround, which I'd like to share for completeness, it's not nice, but it works.

```
# ParNumber is known, ParNameList is a string
pars = []                                                                                          
for i in range(ParNumber):                                                                        
    q = ParNameList[i*10:i*10+10]                                                                      
    q = q[:q.index('\0')]                                                                          
    print q                                                                                        
    pars.append(q)
```

still would like to know, what is the better way